# Unable to label text using config in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have been trying to create a simple stopwatch in tkinter in which I created a loop to update text to new time i.e., the next second in **timer** label as I click **button_1**. I tried to do this with StringVar() as well as .config method but none of them are updating the text in label. The code is below

```
from datetime import *
from time import *

init_time = datetime(100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
running = True

def clock():
    while running == True:
        sleep(1)
        global init_time
        a = init_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        mtime.set(a)
        init_time = init_time + timedelta(seconds=1)

def stop():
    global running
    running = False


main = Tk()
main.geometry("500x200")

mtime = StringVar()

timer = Label(main, textvariable = mtime, width=30, bg="black", fg="white", font=(25))
timer.place(x=90, y=20)
button_1 = Button(main, text = "Start", command = clock()).place(x=170, y=120)
button = Button(main, text = "Stop", command = stop).place(x=250, y=120)

main.mainloop()
```

I even tried to convert the **init_time** to a string because I thought maybe the updates of text work only for strings. The initial GUI window shows but as I click **button_1** it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You did common mistake, look at these two lines

```
button_1 = Button(main, text = "Start", command = clock()).place(x=170, y=120)
button = Button(main, text = "Stop", command = stop).place(x=250, y=120)
```

Note that you have `clock()` and `stop`. First is function invocation, second is function. You should provide function as `command`. Replace `clock()` using `clock`.

Also if you are interested in executing function every *n* miliseconds, please take look at `.after`, consider following simple timer

```
import tkinter as tk
elapsed = 0
def update_timer():
    global elapsed
    elapsed += 1
    timer['text'] = str(elapsed)
    root.after(1000, update_timer)  # 1000 ms = 1 second
root = tk.Tk()
timer = tk.Label(root, text="0")
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Go", command=update_timer)
timer.pack()
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey, yeah I left a mistake but even then the code isn't working. A window of tkinter is being generated but **start** and **stop** button are not working @Daweo